# How to Map array by removing duplicates

Tags: reactjs, foreach, relayjs

I'm developing an application using React.js and using Relay.js for fetching data and have a JSON response for a component like this:

```
{
  outfit(id :"T3V0Zml0Tm9kZTo1") {
    id
    title
    productvariant {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          product {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                brand
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

([github link](https://gist.github.com/imzautomation/b43e68d9053e66d08da330b0962be068)) and I am mapping all the products in a tab like this:

```
<Grid>
  { this.props.outfit.productvariant.edges.map((variantEdge, i) => (
    <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={8} computer={12}>
      <Grid.Column mobile={16} tablet={8} computer={12}>
        <article id ={variantEdge.node.id} >
          <header style = {styles.header}>
            <h2>
              {variantEdge.node.title}
            </h2>
          </header>
        </article>
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
          <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
            <section style = {styles.row}>
              {variantEdge.node.product.edges.map((productEdge,i) =>(
                <section >
                  <section  >
                    <Card   style = {styles.col23} >
                      <Image src="https://cdn.lookastic.com/beige-dress-shirt/roberto-cavalli-ruffled-cotton-voile-shirt-medium-591164.jpg" />
                        <Card.Content  style = {styles.col23}>
                          <Card.Header>{productEdge.node.title}</Card.Header>
                        </Card.Content>
                      </Card>
                    </section>
                  </section>
                ))}
              </section>
```

([github link](https://gist.github.com/imzautomation/472c9ce6db5646d6adc2ae5002ab8db9)). As you can see in response I have products with the field brand. How can I loop Brands and remove the duplicates and map them to a side nav? I want to have a side nav widget next to tab component which will display all the brands available for that particular product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to fix your existing loop in the code above? If so, you can do this a couple of ways.

#### Method 1:

This is the cleanest and most readable version, but it requires you to run some code before and outside your `render()` function.

```
var mySet = new Set();
this.props.outfit.productvariant.edges.forEach((variantEdge) => {
  variantEdge.node.product.edges.forEach((productEdge) =>
    mySet.add(productEdge.node.brand);  //add each brand to a Set, which guarantees uniqueness
  });
});
```

You can then do your `map()` inside the `render()`. Replace this:

```
{variantEdge.node.product.edges.map((productEdge,i) =>(
```

with this:

```
[...mySet].map((productEdge, i) => (
```

---

#### Method 2:

Here is a handy one-liner that you can use. It's not very readable, but works if you want something compact:

```
{variantEdge.node.product.edges.filter((productEdge, i, self) => self.findIndex((p) => {return p.node.brand === productEdge.node.brand}) === i.node.brand).map((productEdge, i) => (
```

The above code assumes the existance of `productEdge.node.brand`.

---

I suggest the former method as it would (probably) perform better and is also easier to read and debug. Note that due to the complexity of your whole object, I may have missed something minor above; the core concept however should work fine.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks alot for the as suggested you u i have used method 1 and its working good.